# Bootstrap conflict or bug - still looking for a solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Today I decided to use bootstrap in order to make a menu but it have come out I've bumped into a weird bug or conflict between jQuery, probably the UI, and Bootstrap. Now, if you want, take a look in at the following picture:

[image]

Now, if I remove the js files of bootstrap it's even worse because those sliders disappear. As you can see, a weir quadratic cut appears on sliders' handles, there are changes in the front - letters are much smaller and closer. Some changes of other text color's appear as well, I've a black text which remains black but tad more transparent. I'd definitely like to continue working with BS, as it'll save me a lot of precious time for future. If it matters, here are the libraries I initialize.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I've taken those from a w3 tutorial but the same effect takes place even when I load from downloaded bootstrap on my pc. So, the question is how to debug this buggy consequence. 
P.S. the navbar shows

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: @KDX2 - Why are you loading jquery several times ?

Comment: it's about 500 lines, so I'll post just the .css instructions regarding the sliders and the navbar.
`<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom"  id = "navigation">
  </div>`  <-navbar
` .slider {
      width: 300px;
      height: 8px;
      background: url('solid attempt.png');
      border-style: none;
      background-size: 300px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }`

Comment: Because I use the normal jquery - once, and I also saw that bootstrap requires its own js and jq libs. When I remove bootstrap's js-s any jq widget goes down.

Comment: Can't someone suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was extremely easy... sometimes the easiest things are much difficult to see. Yeah, adding bootstrap lib's IN MY CASE resulted in a complete re-size of all the sliders I've, as of the front size and the normal images'. In order to solve this, if it happens to you ever, just go to your slider components css and add a `background-size: ;`, play with some values here and it should fix it. Do exactly the same with front sizes. 
That's it.